# How to set a variable to the output `git push` command

Tags: bash, git, variable

I tried this way:

```
pushOut=`git push`
```

But when I try:

```
echo $pushOut
```

I get an empty string

Comment: Look for option `--porcelain` in the manual.

Comment: Use `alias` instead command. such  as `alias ls='ls --color=auto'` Then you can improve your `git push`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`git push` prints to stderr, apparently, so redirect stderr to stdout:

```
$ a=$(git push 2>&1)
$ echo "$a"
Everything up-to-date
```